# iOS - showing an overlay over UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiactivityindicatorview, grand-central-dispatch

I'm downloading data from the web that is then showed on a `UITableView`. Because I want a responsive UI I'm using background downloading with `GCD`. So while the data is downloading there is an empty UITableView displaying (which is not so pretty). And over that there is a `UIActivtyIndicatorView` (setup in IB) spinning.

What I would like is to instead of showing a empty table to display a gray screen with the UIActivityIndicatorView over it.

The code I have so far is this:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(0, 0), ^{

    NSArray *downloadedCareerIds = [CareersParser idsFrom:@"web"];
    NSArray *diskCareerIds = [CareersParser idsFrom:@"disk"];

    BOOL equalIds = [downloadedCareerIds isEqualToArray:diskCareerIds];

    if (!equalIds) {

        DLog(@"ids not equal");

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            /* Send UI updates back to the main thread. */

            // I think here would be a good idead to insert the gray view over the table

            [loadingIndicator startAnimating];
            // Do GUI stuff on the main thread ...
            [loadingIndicator stopAnimating];
            // Remove the gray view?

        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make a gray view with the bounds of the UITableView, and add it as a subview of the tableView. Remove the gray view once you've finished loading.

Comment: Got it to work, but there's a slight delay before the added subview shows up over the tableview so you will see an empty table for half a second and then you will see the loading screen.

Comment: Are you adding the gray view where you have the comment in your question? If so, and want the gray view to not be so delayed, you should add the gray view to the tableview in viewDidLoad. You can save it to an instance variable, or a property (depending on what you are doing) and then remove it as before.